# Can we join the phrases to make a sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-construction

I have the following few phrases

> 1. Sweeping of unfixed edges to be the stable (need to say, by moving unfixed edges, it can be brought to a more stable position)
> 2. affixing of the stable edges with the skeleton edges
> 3. symmetrically preserved closed polygon 
>      (by joing 2, 3 => intersecting of near by fixed edges with skeleton edges are needed to do for obtaining closed polygons having preserved symmetrical property.)

I am stating these phrase in the processing order. So, I want to make one complete sentence by telling all these at the same time.

Here is my effort,

> Sweeping of edges to be the stable **and** affixing of the stable
>   edges with the inclined edges **are** needed to achieve for a
>   symmetrically preserved closed polygon.

So, my question is, if I use **and** and **are**, then would this make sense?

Comment: I think this specific example needs some more context here, otherwise careless joining can make its meaning inconsistent IMHO.

Comment: @Mistu4u: add some explanation..  would it be clear?

Comment: I guess it should have been clear be now after addition of your explanation. But, I don't know why I am unable to interpret the lines properly with a logical relation among them. Perhaps my non-native mind is creating problem here. Hope some native can help you.

Comment: What sort of edges are those which are swept to a more stable position? That needs to be specified so we can distinguish them from the 'inclined' edges to which they are joined.

Comment: @StoneyB: i have updated the post a little bit to get a more clear idea. thanks

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your question, your sentence works after a fashion, but is not very clear, mainly because of the use of the passive voice.

> Sweeping of edges **to be the stable** and affixing of the stable edges
>   with the inclined edges **are needed** to achieve for a symmetrically
>   preserved closed polygon.

Rather than trying to stick the phrases together with conjunctions, it is better to take a more radical approach. Changing word order and using an active voice creates something that is clearer (although I'm not promising my example accurately reflects what you are trying to say).

Something like:

> In order to achieve a symmetrically preserved closed polygon, one must sweep the edges to create stability, and then affix the stable edges to the inclined edges.